# Laravel different config/database.php for production and development

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I'm developing Laravel app on my local server where I have database and also I'm putting in online in production environment.

Each environment has different db connection information. So far I dealt with this just commenting information when I'm committing like this:

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => $host,
    'database'  => $database,
    'username'  => $username,
    'password'  => $password,
    // 'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    // 'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    // 'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    // 'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    // 'unix_socket'   => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
],
```

but this is sure wrong approach. How can I set different database connection information for each environment is some better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the .env file instead.. Have a .env in your production and one in your development..

Take a look at your .env.example

[Laravel Environment Configuration Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#environment-configuration)

Comment: ...and you can also read Laravels extensive documentation on the subject.